# SlidingPaneLayout programmatically change the width of the left panel

Tags: java, android, slidingpanelayout

What I want is that the 1st time that the user open my app the left panel can use the full screen!
then I need to resize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the SlidingPaneLayout source :[SlidingPaneLayout.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.java), you will find **DEFAULT_OVERHANG_SIZE = 32** in this class as the default size of the overhang for a pane in the open state.

Since this is a private static constant，you need to change it into a variable and create its set method.

Take care of onMeasure() method and good luck.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the exact same result but I really can't :-/ I created MySlidingPaneLayout extends SlidingPaneLayout and tried to override private static final int DEFAULT_OVERHANG_SIZE = 2; but it's not enough. What's about onMeasure()? Should I override that as well? And how?

Comment: I managed to make it using https://github.com/BurntBrunch/android-WrappingSlidingPane